# Powershell email script blocked by Outlook

Tags: email, powershell, outlook

I am running a C program that is scanning a log file on a continuous loop. Once certain conditions are met, the program generates a Powershell script to be executed. This script is a basic script to send an email to multiple recipients. Here is the script:

```
$o = New-Object -com Outlook.Application
$mail = $o.CreateItem(0)
Sleep 1
$mail.subject = "Auto Report"
$mail.HTMLBody = "This is an automated message."
$mail.To = "recipient@email.com; "
Sleep 1
$mail.Send()
```

The script has been tested and proven to work for several months. However, on occasion, Outlook will force the user to click "allow" to send the email.

I can't post an image just yet, but here is a link to the symptom I'm describing:
[link](http://www.msoutlook.info/question/883)

Because this is supposed to be an automatic program, this is a problem. The program must be able to run in the background, with or without the presence of a user.

This program runs on a workplace work station, and I do not have admin privileges to alter the settings on outlook, or to update any antivirus files. So far, IT has not been helpful to my problem.

I was hoping somebody could give any insight as to why this is happening, and what would allow Outlook to send the messages.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I'd re-code that to use the EWS managed API, and get rid of Outlook.

Comment: To supress that message altogether you need to run outlook as administrator on the affected machine and go into the trust center > programmatic settings and set to "never warn". Obviously there are caveats with this approach but the option is there. With the code you have that would be the only way. I'm not sure how to do it but thors hammer had a good suggestion

Comment: Check Glen Scales blog.  Lots of good examples there.

Comment: Just use `send-mailmessage` and bypass outlook entirely.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, your choices are

1. Make sure you are using the latest version of Outlook along with an up-to-date antivirus app - Outlook will not display security prompts then.
2. Switch to Extended MAPI (C++ or Delphi only).
3. Use a MAPI wrapper such as [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (I am its author) that uses Extended MAPI internally and is not affected by the security prompts.